# Minimum number of fire balls required to kill every archer?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

Polycrap  wants to kill a line of archers ,the only weapon he has  is a fire ball. If Polycarp hits the i-th archer with his fire ball (they are numbered from left to right), the archer loses **a** health points.

At the same time the spell damages the archers adjacent to the i-th (if any) — they lose **b**  (**1 ≤ b < a ≤ 10**) health points each.

As the extreme archers (i.e. archers numbered 1 and n) are very far, the fire ball cannot reach them. Polycarp can hit any other archer with his fire ball.

The amount of health points for each archer is known. An archer will be killed when this amount is less than 0. What is the minimum amount of spells Polycarp can use to kill all the enemies?

Polycarp can throw his fire ball into an archer if the latter is already killed.

**Description of I/O**

```
INPUT -The first line of the input contains three integers n, a, b (3 ≤ n ≤ 10; 1 ≤ b < a ≤ 10). 
       The second line contains a sequence of n integers — h1, h2, ..., hn (1 ≤ hi ≤ 15), where hi is the amount of health points the i-th archer has.

OUTPUT- In the first line print t — the required minimum amount of fire balls.
        In the second line print t numbers — indexes of the archers that Polycarp should hit to kill all the archers in t shots.
```

Now I have written a recursive function that takes an array of current health of archers and generate each possible attack  until all archers are dead and returns the minimum.

But this approach is too slow,How can this be solved efficiently?

Note: I am not necessarily interested in optimizing my own solution ,But open to any other solution that might be faster.

[Problem Link with some test cases](http://codeforces.com/contest/6/problem/D)

[My current solution](http://ideone.com/PZuC4u)

Comment: You should post your code here instead of a link (because of the risk that the link may not exist as long as this question)

Comment: Hint: think how you can kill the first alive archer on every step. And how many wounded archers there can be if you're following this strategy

Comment: I dont get this sentence: "Polycarp can throw his fire ball into an archer if the latter is already killed."  So even if the archer's hp goes <= 0, you can still throw fireball to it and burn its adjacent archers?

Comment: @shole This condition is a necessity since he can't attack someone at the extremes so if the player next to the extremities has already died he can still attack him to damage the one at the extreme.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that to kill leftest archer, you need to through fireball either at him or at the next to him archer.

1. Kill 1-st and n-th archers.
2. Start from the left. You can kill the leftest archer by throwing fireball at him or at his right companion. Arrange array DP which will have entries like number of archers left and life points for leftest three (life points for other in AD). So, try one of the two possibilities, check if you already was in such situation, if yes use answer from DP, if not go recursively down, then unwinding recursion add data into array DP on every level of the recursion.

Comment: @Deniss you are right, thank you. I've removed second step,  that step, i thought, would decrease size of memoization table.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. recursion tends to be slower because of the overhead of the recursive calls.
2. I think your recursion might compute the costs for the same situation (health distibution) multible times only because the leading attacks were different. So keeping a map of already calculated health-distributions and the minimal cost of it should resolve this issue.
3. You do not always need to calculate until all are dead. You can skip the rest of the calculation as soon as your costs are higher (or equal) than the best solution you have already found.

Comment: 1. I am open to any other non recursive approach.  2. I have already kept a hashmap of visited states for which i have already found a solution. 3 This could speed somethings but I am not sure how much.   Again I don't want necessarily my solution to be optimized 'm open to other approaches

Answer (score 0):

First and the last archer can be killed in only one possible way, by shooting at the adjacent archers. Adjust the lineup after killing those two. If there are archers left alive go to next step.

Have only one array. No need to copy the array, since we will recover from the shoot. How does recovering works? Just add what you previously subtracted.

Leftmost living archer (LLA) can be shot at either by shooting him directly, or by shooting the next one (no point in shooting the previous one, since he's dead). So your recursive function should shoot LLA, recover the array, then shoot the archer adjacent to him.

To reduce the search you don't actually "shoot" the archer (begin, shoot, call, recover, shoot, call, recover, end), but call the function telling it to shoot the archer as the first step of the function (begin, shoot, call_to_shoot, call_to_shoot, recover, end). Why? Because if shooting call is to shoot adjacent to LLA then you don't "call to shoot" LLA anymore. That path was already covered.

Additional optimization is, if it requires the same amount of `b` shoots to kill LLA as `a` shoots (in math-speak `ceil(x/b) < floor(x/a + 1)`) then skip the call that shoots him directly (`a` shoots), and go immediately to shooting the adjacent (`b` shoots).

You should book-keep the value of least amount of shoots necessary to kill them all. If during search you exceed this value don't go further.

Answer (score 0):

What a great problem, I learn a lot from this problem as well. Below solution are all 0-based.

*(My solution was inspired by @Yola, please UV to him if this is helpful)*

---

I believe there is several valid DP recurrence for this problem, here is the one I used:

DP(i,a,b,c) := The minimum total # of fireballs needed to kill all [0,i] archers, while we throw `a` balls to the *i-1 th* archer, `b` balls to the *i th* archer, `c` balls to the *i+1 th* archer

I define *INF* if such a state is invalid (i.e. such arrangement cannot kill all [0,i] archers). Initially all states are *INF*.

Notice that in given requirement,  i<=10 & a,b,c <= **16** (this one causes me 2 wrong answers submissions, because of the less than 0 instead of less than or equal to 0). Also solution always exist.

After we define the state, now we can try to make up the other three components of a DP solution: ***base case, recurrence formula, final answer inquiry***

---

### Base Case

Note that we cannot throw balls at the ends, therefore the only way to kill them is to throw enough fireballs to the one *next* to them.

To kill the *0-th* archer, we can just brute force throwing [0,17] fireballs to the *1st* archer, also brute all [0,17] fireballs to the *2nd* archer. Of course take the minimum among them iff they can kill both *0-th* and *1st* archers.

```
//base case
FOR(i,0,17) FOR(j,0,17)
    if(i*a+j*b>h[1] && i*b > h[0])
        dp[1][0][i][j] = min(dp[1][0][i][j], i);
```

### Recurrence Formula

When we got all possible ways (i.e. states) of throwing fireballs to kill all [0,i-1] archers, we can use these information to calculate the state of killing [0,i] archers. (If you visualize it, it's like sliding window of a 3 unit width, all the way from left to right)

The formula is
DP(i, a, b, c) = min(DP(i-1, x, a, b) + b) for all x <= 16 **AND** (a,b,c) can kill the *i-th* archer

### Answer Inquiry

Note that we cannot throw balls to the last archer like the first one, so here we have to do a checking like we did in setting up the base case.

The answer is the minimum of all *DP(n-2, a, b, 0)* for a,b <= 16 **AND** (a,b,0) can kill both *n-2 th and n-1 th (last)* archers.

Remember you can just loop all to take the minimum as **solution must exist**.

---

The actual path of the states (print out which archer you have to throw the fireballs) is a matter of implementation. Here I simply used a simple recursion which is *O(n)*. The whole solution thus is *O(n^5)*  where *n~20*

Here is my accepted code

```cs
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define FOR(x,y,z) for(int (x)=(y); (x)<(z); (x)++)
#define FER(x,y,z) for(int (x)=(y); (x)<=(z); (x)++)
#define INF 1<<28
using namespace std;

int n,a,b,dp[11][17][17][17], h[11];

//Trace the actual solution
void printAns(int idx, int aa, int bb, int cc){
    if(idx<0) return;
    FOR(i,0,bb) printf("%d ", idx+1);
    FOR(i,0,17){
        if(dp[idx-1][i][aa][bb]+bb == dp[idx][aa][bb][cc]){
            printAns(idx-1, i,aa,bb);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FOR(i,0,11) FOR(j,0,17) FOR(k,0,17) FOR(p,0,17) dp[i][j][k][p] = INF;
    
    scanf("%d%d%d", &n,&a,&b);
    FOR(i,0,n) scanf("%d", &h[i]);
    
    //base case
    FOR(i,0,17) FOR(j,0,17)
        if(i*a+j*b>h[1] && i*b > h[0])
            dp[1][0][i][j] = min(dp[1][0][i][j], i);
    
    // dp recursion
    FOR(i,1,n-1) FOR(j,0,17) FOR(k,0,17) FOR(x,0,17) FOR(y,0,17)
        if((j+x)*b+k*a > h[i])
            dp[i][j][k][x] = min(dp[i][j][k][x] , dp[i-1][y][j][k] + k);
    
    // ans (handle side case)
    int ans = INF, aa,bb;
    FOR(i,0,17) FOR(j,0,17)
        if(j*a+i*b>h[n-2] && j*b >h[n-1]){
            if(dp[n-2][i][j][0] < ans){
                ans = dp[n-2][i][j][0];
                aa = i; bb = j;
            }
        }
    
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    printAns(n-2, aa, bb, 0);
    return 0;
}
```